# How to exctract MAX value of a column and return column name to save it as a variant

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, opencsv

I am a very beginner enthusiastic programmer wanna be. I am trying to compare two columns of a csv which I got from Google trends and extract the "Winner word" into a variant or list. So I could compare to other keywords in trends. So far, I managed:

The csv always looks like this:

```
date,VR,metaverse
2004-01-01,17,0
2004-02-01,17,0
2004-03-01,18,0
2004-04-01,16,0
2004-05-01,17,0
2004-06-01,17,0
```

in:

```
csv1 = pd.read_csv ("search_trends.csv").drop("date", axis=1)
csv1 = pd.DataFrame(csv1)
result1 = csv1.max(axis=1)
result1.index = csv1.idxmax(axis=1)
```

out:

```
VR    17
VR    17
VR    18
VR    16
VR    17
      ..
VR    45
VR    46
VR    45
VR    44
VR    40

Length: 226, dtype: int64
['VR', 'metaverse']
```

The trick here is, that I might not know the names of the column, therefore it needs to be universal somehow.

Comment: Do you happen to have an example snippet of what the csv file looks like ?

Comment: Also give your desired output from this snippet

Comment: Updated the question with the csv. 

So desired would be to compare these two columns, save the winner column name in order to request a new CSV from Google Trends, including this winner word and another word from a keyword list csv. Complicated i know..

Answer (score 0):

you can also access a column by index and retrieve its name, but you have to know the index:

```
import pandas as pd

foo = pd.DataFrame()
foo['a'] = [1, 2, 3]

col_index = 0

max_of_column = max(foo.iloc[:, col_index])
name_of_column = foo.columns[col_index]
```